# Examples of when $0\cdot x\neq 0$ or $x+0\neq x$.

Tags: logic, axioms

I'm trying to prove that the arithmetic axioms are independent by constructing a model in which all bar one of the axioms are satisfied, for each of the axioms below.

> A first order theory with arithmetic has equality, one constant ($\mathbf{0}$), one unary function ('successor') and two binary functions ($+,\cdot$).
>
> 1. $(\forall x)( x^+\neq0)$
> 2. $(\forall x)(\forall y)(x^+=y^+\implies x=y)$
> 3. $(\forall x)(x+0=x)$
> 4. $(\forall x)(\forall y)(x+y^+=(x+y)^+)$
> 5. $(\forall x)(x\cdot 0=0)$
> 6. $(\forall x)(\forall y)(x\cdot (y^+)=(x\cdot y)+x)$
> 7. Induction

I would appreciate some help constructing models in which the 3rd and 5th axioms are false in particular.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider $\{0,1,\ldots\}$ with the same $+$, ${}^+$ and $0$, but a different
multiplication: $a \cdot b = 1 + ab$ (where $ab$ is the usual product).  This
satisfies all but (5).

Answer (score 2):

All but 3: On $\mathbb N_0$, define $x+ y=(x+_{\text{standard}}y)^+$. Then use 5 and 6 to *define* multiplication recursively.
Actually, one verifies that this results in  $x\cdot y=x^+\cdot_{\text{standard}}y$

Answer (score 1):

In the same fashion of Robert's answer, redefine $a+b=a^+ + b$.
This should violate the third axiom.

Comment: Actually it also violates 4th and 6th axioms